# Bluetooth does not detect any devices - Dell Inspiron 15/ 12.04LTS

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

The bluetooth adapter is visible and not blocked, but does not detect any devices at all while attempting to pair.

rfkill list

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lsusb :

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I searched and found that issue lies with Broadcom BT. Is there no way around it?

Comment: What is your kernel version. `uname -r` ? But should work with all supported kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6 3.2.0-86-generic

Comment: I checked. They backported support of this chip to 3.2. It should work.

Comment: So I will try the method you suggested by you in other thread and report back to you with the result

Comment: Exactly. Please do.

Comment: The dmesg log could give you some more information. On my XPS 13 9343 I needed to extract some files from the broadcom Windows driver. It is described here: http://tech.sybreon.com/2015/03/15/xps13-9343-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: @Pilot6 It worked like a charm :) Thanks

Comment: @Pilot6  It stopped working when i restarted my laptop this morning. When i tried the method again, it worked for a while and then switched off.

Comment: @PrashantSingh I suggest reporting the bug to launchpad. This is not the right place for extended debugging.